# Why do I have overflow with a height of 100%?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm relatively new to web development and I can't quite figure out why I am getting overflow with a height set to 100% using flexbox. I would like to have the columns fill the entire height of the container but not overflow. Any help would be much appreciated. Also, I'm certain this is super simple.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<head>
    <style>
        .leftCol{
            background-color: gray;
            text-align: center;
            padding-right: 10px;
            flex: 25%;
        }
        .rightCol{
            background-color: lightblue;
            text-align: center;
            flex: 75%;
        }
        .row {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: nowrap;
            margin: 0;
        }
        .canvas{
            border:1px solid #000000;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body >
  <div class="row">
    <div class="leftCol">
        Col1
        <canvas class="canvas" id="architectureCanvas"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="rightCol">
        Col2
        <canvas class="canvas" id="architectureCanvas"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jp64mqr7/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you have overflow is that you set canvas height to 100% and also you have some text above that takes some space as well, and as a result, you got overflow because you need more space than you have.

To fix it, you should probably:
On the leftCol and the righCol you should add:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
```

Also, on .canvas you should add:

```
height: auto;        
flex-grow: 1;
```

JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/velid/6eo45ycj/8/

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Welcome to StackOverflow!